# SQL - Grouping results by totaling

Tags: sql, oracle

The below query gives me an output of two columns:

```
Day Num_Users_Retained
0   209312
1   22139
2   11457
```

And so on, all the way to 259 (Every day in the year 2012)..However I want day 0 to include the sum of all the values in num_users_retained from 0 to 259...and then I want day 1 to include the sum of all values from 1-259, and so on until I get to the last day. Here is the original query:

```
--Retention since January 1,2012--
select retention as Day,count(retention) as Num_Users_Retained
from (select player_id,round(init_dtime-create_dtime,0) as retention
from player
where Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-jan-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
and init_dtime is not null)
Group by retention
order by 1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select retention as Day
     , Sum(count(retention)) over(order by retention desc) as Num_Users_Retained
 from (select player_id
            , round(init_dtime-create_dtime,0) as retention
        from player
       where Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-jan-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
         and init_dtime is not null
       )
Group by retention
order by retention
```

Comment: very close, I just edited slightly to what I used to make the query run. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use Analytic functions

```
select
    day,
    num_users_retained,
    sum(num_users_retained) over (order by day) as total_num_users_retained
from churn
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24e02/1

This query is written over your resultset. You may be able to apply this to your original query.

Comment: I tried adding that in but it keeps saying 'not a single-group function..i simply added my original query in parenthesis in the "churn" area..am I on the right path? Thank you for your response.

Comment: The second approach should work, but may not be very optimal. I did not want to provide a query without testing. That's why I did not attempt modifying the original query. Build a sample schema in SQL Fiddle and we will solve it.

Comment: I built my own. Refer this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a722/4  Please select/highlight individual SQL query and Execute.

Comment: Geordee- Thank you very much for trying to troubleshoot this with me...however I am going to use the below option as it was pretty close to right, i just had to make a few slight changes.